# Matching two rows in a single table if two specific keys have different values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `settings` in that there are two columns and data like following.

```
settings           value
-------            ------
depots             12
projectid          156
client             icici bank
clientvisits       2
DBname             icicibank
progress           true
displayvisits      2
visitsskipped      0
```

Here , the values of rows `clientvisits` and `displayvisits` should be same always.
I want a query which display the only these two fields along with values if their values are different. That means if `clientvisits=2 and displayvisits=4` then it should throw an error (I mean it should display the output along with values).

I tried  by using self join  like this  but it is not working.

```
select * from settings TS,settings TS1
where TS.settings=TS1.settings and CONVERT(integer,ts.value)=1

select * from settings TS,settings TS1
where TS.settings=TS1.settings and ts.setting like 'visitstodisplay'=1
```

Also, I tried to do some thing else but I didn't get.
Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: How does this involve MySQL and SSIS?

Comment: it doesnt involves MySql and SSis. as i am new to this site.so i have tagged  them so that the people in that may  give the better answer or query.

Comment: @user19858 Can you show us exactly what you want your output to look like? I can't work out if you want one row with values in different columns in that one row, or you want just those 2 rows, but only if the values are different...

Comment: Hi Mark, yes you are right i just want those two rows, only if the values are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a join on `Value <> Value` for the settings you are looking for.

```
select S1.Settings as Settings1,
       S1.Value as Value1,
       S2.Settings as Settings2,
       S2.Value as Value2
from Settings as S1
  inner join Settings as S2
    on S1.Value <> S2.Value and
       S1.Settings = 'clientvisits' and
       S2.Settings = 'displayvisits'
```

Result:

```
Settings1            Value1               Settings2            Value2
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
clientvisits         2                    displayvisits        4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE Settings = 'displayvisits') d
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE Settings = 'clientvisits') c ON d.Value <> c.Value
```

Will return you both settings in a single row.

Answer (score -1):

```
select
    TS.clientvisits,
    TS.displayvisits 
from settings TS,settings TS1
where 
    TS.settings=TS1.settings 
    and TS.clientvisits!=TS.displayvisits
```

Comment: Hi maddy, thank you for your answer but  i have tried your query but it is not working as here we have to comapare  two rows as clentvisits and displayvists are rows. but the query u have provided is for columns. as there are only two columns in this table  they are settings and value in table setting